# Http failure response for (unknown url) - Angular Universal(SSL) on Docker

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, angular5, server-side-rendering

The error occurs only when api is HTTPS.
The testing site is hosted on Digital Ocean.But the below setup is working on my local(MAC Os) with self signed certificate.

**Things which i have tried:**

- firewall disabled (sudo ufw disable) in digitalocean
- Node SSL Verification disabled (**NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0**)
- No cors issue , I have already allowed any client from api

Below is my docker compose setup

1. web - which is nginx container
2. laravel - which is an api
3. angualr - Angular universal which consumes api from web
4. database - mariadb database

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  laravel:
    build: ./laravel/docker/php
    depends_on:
      - database
    expose:
      - 9000  
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/laravel
      - $HOME/.composer/:$HOME/.composer/
      - ./laravel/docker/php/php-custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-custom.ini


  angular:
    build: ./angular
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - ./angular:/var/www/angular:rw
    depends_on:
      - laravel
    links:
      - laravel:laravel

  web:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./dh-param/dhparam-2048.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem:ro
      - /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/fullchain.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/fullchain.pem
      - /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/privkey.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/privkey.pem
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    links:
      - laravel:laravel
      - angular:angular
    depends_on:
      - laravel
      - angular
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=fabivo.com, portal.fabivo.com , api.fabivo.com, shop.fabivo.com
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - api.fabivo.com
          - portal.fabivo.com
          - shop.fabivo.com
          - fabivo.com
          - api.paisaclub.com

  database:
    build: ./laravel/docker/mariadb
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=homestead"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

volumes:
  mysqldata:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name fabivo.com;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
                   # NOTE THERE IS NO TRAILING SLASH AT THE END. NO TRAILING SLASH. NO SLASH. NO!
                    proxy_pass http://angular:9000; # <--- THIS DOES NOT HAVE A TRAILING '/'
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.fabivo.com portal.fabivo.com shop.fabivo.com;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fabivo.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

     location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
            }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
                    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;
                    #CSP
                   # add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self'; default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; font-src 'self' data: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests;" always;
                    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" always;
                }
}
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
const domino = require('domino');
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
//import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();
const compression = require('compression');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

//
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), 'utf8').toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
    value: () => {
        return {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        };
    },
});
global['document'] = win.document;
global['$'] = require('jquery');
global['jQuery '] = global['$'];
global['Materialize'] = win.Materialize;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));


app.use(compression());

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), { maxAge: '1y' }));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        req: req,
        res: res
    });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

here is minimal reproduction repo
https://github.com/ssatz/Angular-SSR-HTTPS-Error
Deployed to heroku [HEROKU](https://paisaclub.herokuapp.com/faq)

Note : This is working perfectly in my local with Self Signed certificate.

Comment: Update :   here is minimal reproduction repo
https://github.com/ssatz/Angular-SSR-HTTPS-Error
Deployed to heroku [HEROKU](https://paisaclub.herokuapp.com/faq)

Note : This is working perfectly in my local with Self Signed certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to SSL configuration.
Incase if any one having the issue, change secp384r1 to prime256v1

```
ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1;
```